# Connect to SQL Server using knexjs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, knex.js

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using this knexjs code

```
  test: {
    client: process.env.DB_CLIENT,
    connection: {
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
      options: {
        port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT),
        trustedConnection: true
      },
      // encrypt: true
    },
  };
```

But I am not able to do it and using this crediential I am able to connect to SQL Server          Management Studio. Error while connecting SQL Server with knexjs is:

> Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - Could not connect (sequence)

I have tried many solutions but failed.
Please help me.

Comment: _using this crediential I am able to connect to SQL Server Management Studio._ Nope, SQL Server Management Studio is just a client tool, you cannot connect to it. SSMS is used to connect to and manage SQL Server instances where the databases actually reside. So where's your SQL Server instance? Where's this NodeJS code running? (i.e.: is it inside a Docker container or one of VS Code's devcontainers?)

Comment: I am running this project on my local machine and SQL Server installed on my machine and I am trying to connect to that server.

Comment: Are you using an SQL Server Express edition? Have you checked in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager to see which Server Protocols you have enabled on your instance? Connections from NodeJS require that the TCP/IP protocol is enabled but for Express editions this is disabled by default, and even when enabled it usually isn't listening on tcp/1433.